# How can he assume SD of population equals to SD of sample means?

Tags: statistical-inference, standard-deviation

I'm referring to this KhanAcademy video: https://youtu.be/bekNKJoxYbQ?t=445.

My question: How can he approximate the SD of the population to be equal to SD of the sample means? Isn't that SD of the sample means would be wayyy higher than the SD of the population?

Is this a wrong assumption, or is there any reason behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: The Berry Esseen theorem gives you how far off the actual distribution is from the empirical distribution.

Comment: Standard deviation of the population means how much the individuals vary. Now if you were to start taking multiple samples and look at the means of the samples, those will vary a lot _less_ than the individual measurements. Evidently that is _not_ what the video is about, however.

Answer (score 0):

He's not comparing the SD of the population to the SD of the sample *means*. He's saying that the SD of the population of all apple weights is approximately the SD of the *sample of 36* apple weights, i.e. $\sigma\approx s$. The intuition is that the histogram of 36 weights should have a similar spread compared to the histogram of all 200,000 weights.

Comment: Yeah, but how can that assumption be made? That is what I don't understand. From simulations that I have made so far (and from what I've seen), SD of sample means always is significantly different than SD of the population.

Comment: What formula are you using to compute $s$?